# css transform have no transition on hover and remain static on mouseout

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have coded a compass and a compass needle for a header, when you hover over the compass the needle spins at a 720 degree angle, however, i want a way so that when i move my mouse off the compass it doesn't reverse. SOrry if i'm overlooking an easy solution but here's my current code to explain what im doing better.

```
.arrow{
    width:100px; 
    height:100px;
    background-image:url(https://dl.dropbox.com/u/81513943/Monolith/images/compass.png);
    background-size:100px;
}

.arrowhover{
    position:absolute;
    margin-top:-100px;
    background-size:100px;
    width:100px;
    -webkit-transition: all 1.7s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 1.7s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 1.7s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 1.7s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 1.7s ease-in-out;
    height:100px;
}

.arrowhover:hover{      
    -webkit-transform: rotate(1440deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(1440deg);
    -webkit-transition: all 1.7s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 1.7s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 1.7s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 1.7s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 1.7s ease-in-out;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);
}
```

so yeh, compass is normal, hover it spins 720 degrees and on mouse out i want no animation, is there a way to do this?

p.s im useless at jquery and javascript

Comment: Don't know enough to help you out code-wise, but I can tell you that the reason that it's reversing is because the CSS you're using only will spin it once it is hovered, so once it is not hovered the process is reversed. Theoretically, you could call a function onmouseover using JavaScript to rotate the image. This way there would be no reversal.

Comment: Could you describe "no animation"? Do you want to go back to initial position without animation? Or to stop there and don't move when you mouseout?

Comment: @FabrícioMatté the needle appears to be in the same position as the start as its a 720 degree turn but yes i want it to stay the same after the initial animation without an animation, so in other words, animate on hover and stay still until you hover again

Comment: check this http://jsfiddle.net/rHpDn/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check my updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rHpDn/3/

I added `transition: all 0s ease-in-out;` to .arrow, so it does't have a transition back anymore.